# Can't Connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' when /etc/my.cnf is present

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Context -
I was experiencing this issue talked about here in this [article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/13/solve-query-failures-regarding-only_full_group_by-sql-mode/) while working on a rails application that connects to a SQL database.

`Mysql2::Error - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column`

The solution is to set the sql mode to a more lenient setting.

To do this I created the /etc/my.cnf file and added a single line:
`sql_mode=''`

I then restarted the MySQL service through brew. That is when I started experiencing the
rails `Can't Connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1` error. I had to delete the /etc/my.cnf file and set the sql_mode from my local configuration in /Users/me/.my.cnf. My question is why?

Comment: It's possible you had a syntax error in the my.cnf --  So when MySQL tried to start .. IT failed.  What do the logs say?

Comment: Personally I don't know if single quotes are acceptable in the `cnf` file .. I would start by try using doubles -->  `sql_mode =""`  Confirmed tested .. This works ..

Comment: Single-quotes are fine, I use them. I suspect some other change occurred. I would look in the error log for clues about why the MySQL Server did not start.

Comment: My other comment is that you should fix your queries instead of making the sql mode more lenient. The error exists because the queries risk returning invalid results.

Comment: ^ What @BillKarwin said --  `sql_mode=""` will allow zero dates, will allow division by zero and  other quirky whacky things.   I suggest you look into the [Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) and make that decision based on educating yourself about what they do/don't do  ...  And change your queries accordingly.

Comment: Using the second answer from this post-
https://serverfault.com/questions/42531/where-is-my-mysql-log-on-os-x
-I tried to locate my error logs, and I haven't had any success. So I don't have a way to give you that info. I'll look for a way to turn on the error logging and re-create the /etc/my.cnf file exactly the way I had it.